# Angular: empty array as property of typed object

Tags: angular, typescript

so I have a model:

```
export interface Clan {
  name: string;
  members: [string];
  invitees: [string];
}
```

When the user creates a new clan it does not has yet *invitees*, only one *member*.

```
newClan = {
   name: form.value.name;
   members: [user.id];
   invitees: [];
}
```

And this gives the an error

> Property '0' is missing in type '[]' but required in type '[string]'.

Of course I could use values as **null** or **undefined**, also or just define *invitees* in the model as **not required**:

```
export interface Clan {
  name: string;
  members: [string];
  invitees?: [string];
}
```

But is there a way to have an *invitees* empty array on the creation of a new clan?

Comment: Just an FYI. `[string]` is how you declare a tuple that will contain a string in typescript, at least the start of a tuple. Usually, you will have more than one type in a tuple. `string[]` is how you declare an array of type string.

Comment: Now I understand, Thx @R.Richards. Went back to read about tuples. Your answer is actually the correct one!

Answer (score 6):

I guess, it might be reasonable to use `string[]` instead of `[string]`, because `[string]` is an array with exact one string in it.

```
export interface Clan {
  name: string;
  members: string[];
  invitees: string[];
}

const newClan: Clan = {
   name: form.value.name;
   members: [user.id];
   invitees: [];
}
```

**Edit:** @R. Richards comment offers a good explanation. Read [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) more about tupels in TypeScript:

> Tuple types allow you to express an array with a fixed number of
>   elements whose types are known, but need not be the same.

Comment: I prefer R. Richards explication. Because it explains why I still can have multiple values in what I though was an array. (see comments of question) Thank you!

Comment: That's true and a good point. Therefore I added a link to the accordant TypeScript part about tupels.

Comment: Strange they define it with "fixed number of elements" as I still can push new elements into it as long as I'm using the same type. Or I am misinterpreting the definition?

Comment: Mmh. If I do something like `const bar: [number] = [1, 1];`, which is one element too many, I get the following error: _Type '[number, number]' is not assignable to type '[number]'. Types of property 'length' are incompatible._

Comment: However, `string[]` is not a tuple but an array. Therefore you can push element by element.

Comment: I see. I've tested. Thank you very much.

It's just confusing because you can make a model with tuple as key and then use that key as an array. In the example of the OP, I am able to change the amount of values in the members and invitees keys.